# How to show some content when android app in onStop

Tags: android, android-activity, android-progressbar, activity-lifecycle

I have a simple question: is there a way to show something, like a progress bar, when the app is onStop?
Because my app does a lot of computation, and when it is actually doing that goes on onStop and a black screen is showed, finally when the computation is done it return to the normal screen.
So, it is all correct in a functional point of view, but aesthetically it is not so good.
Have you got any tip?

Comment: If an Activity goes to `onStop` then its not visible to user anymore . You misunderstood the Concept of Activity lifecycle . take good Read of [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) .. For computation part which takes longer you should be using a background thread . Do not do any long running task on main thread this result in an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr).

Comment: Sorry, I was a little ambiguous. I know what onStop imply for an app. But, because I want something to show while it goes on that step of lifecycle, I wanted to know if there was a way to "swindle" the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to prevent your device from going to sleep while the computation is running? That is called a `WakeLock`, and it basically prevents your activity from turning off the screen. Be careful to use it sparingly, to avoid draining your users battery.

It's very easy to do this programatically:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)
    }
}
```

Or you can add an xml attribute to the view you want to show:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more information and details have a [look at the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the app doesn't go to sleep while the computation is taking much time. Summarizing: I launch the app, then I need to select some images, when I selected them, the computation start and if I select a lot of images this will take more time, so the activity goes in onStop and a black screen shows up till the computation end, and the normal layout come back.

Comment: That sounds more like a threading issue. If the device "freezes" during this time, e.g. you cannot do anything for a period of time, you are blocking the main thread.

Comment: Yes, I think that is due to the heavy computation that is doing. So there is nothing to do?

Comment: There are too much options to list here. Maybe coroutines is the simplest way to get started. Have a look here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/coroutines-basic-jvm.html